# How do i get the container name of a component within itself?

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

How do i get the container name of a component within itself?

`this.componentNameStream` used to kind of work in [1.11](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/pull/10093/files#diff-9c19259bf74e3317e9023ca9d58e5cf8R15).

```
// in components/my-component.js
export default Component.extend({
   layoutName: "components/my-component",
   partialName: function() {
     //return "my-component"; somehow....
   }.property(); 
});
```

why? for subclassing reasons:

```
// in components/blah.js
export default MyComponent.extend({});

// in templates/components/my-component.hbs
<div class="someLayout">
  // partialName is now "components/blah"
  {{ partial partialName }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I fully understand what you are trying to do but the usage of `{{partial}}` is not recommended (see https://github.com/dockyard/styleguides/blob/master/ember.md#templates).

Why not simply share a template between two components using `layoutName`?

```
// in components/my-foo.js
export default Component.extend({
  showSomething: false
});

// in components/my-bar.js
export default MyFooComponent.extend({
  layoutName: "components/my-foo",
  showSomething: true
});

// in templates/components/my-foo.hbs
<div class="someLayout">
  {{#if showSomething}}
     I am the bar component!
  {{/if}}
</div>
```

If you really need to use a partial, you could replace `showSomething` by a property which contains the name of the partial to be displayed as a string.

Comment: i wanted the suclasses to have the same layout, but different template. components can't have templates, so i have `render` instead---keeping the parent class independent of it's children. i just wanted everything to work automatically and coherently again. thanks for you time.